# When i update my date filed is not updated.i am using mysql database

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jsp, hql

```
qr=ss.createQuery("update Adddata set std_name='" + 
request.getParameter("std_name") + "',std_sex='" +  
request.getParameter("std_sex")+ "',std_mob='" +     
request.getParameter("std_mob")+ "',std_email='" + 
request.getParameter("std_email")+ "',std_course='" + 
request.getParameter("std_course")+ "',std_add='" + 
request.getParameter("std_add")+ "',std_fname='" + 
request.getParameter("std_fname")+ "',std_date='" + 
request.getParameter("std_date")+"'
where stid ='"+request.getParameter("std_id")+"'");
```

Answer (score 0):

The Mysql default date format is `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Kindly check your  `request.getParameter("std_date")` value date format.

eg: date: `2017-10-20`

Update HQL query

```
 Query query = session.createQuery("update Adddata set std_name= :stdname" +
                        " ,std_sex = :stdsex "+
                        ... //do the same for other values
                        " ,std_date = :stddate"
                        " where stid = :stdid");
    query.setParameter("stdname", request.getParameter("std_name"));
    query.setParameter("stdsex", request.getParameter("std_sex"));
    ... //do the same for other values
```

To set date value

```
    query.setDate("stddate", request.getParameter("std_date"));
```

or if you consider time also

```
query.setTimestamp("stddate", dateObj)
query.setParameter("stdid", request.getParameter("std_id"));
int result = query.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: request.getParameter value date fomat is yyyy-mm-dd.so how i update my date using this format with HQL query, give me full description.

Comment: check the edited answer. for more info [HQL update date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291620/how-to-assign-date-parameters-to-hibernate-query-for-current-timezone)